# Retrieving ViewModel data collection is null

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am passing model from view to controller. in my viewmodel `List<TradeLaneDetailsDTO>` is null always, and i am passing my data through ajax. what is the problem in my code.
please help me...

here is my viewmodel

```
public class SLAViewModel 
    {
        public List<TradeLaneDetailsDTO> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

here is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveSLA", "SLAMgmt", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-horizontal", @role = "form", id = "frmEstDays" }))
                {

              for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++)
              {
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Items.ElementAt(i).legname, Model.Items.ElementAt(i).legname, new { @class = "col-md-4" })               
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Items.ElementAt(i).estddays, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", MaxLength = "10" })     
                            </div>
                       </div>

              }

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="offset-3 col-md-8">
                        <button id="btnSave" type="button" title="Save" class="btn btn-success" onclick="getPage1('@Url.Action("SaveSLA", "SLAMgmt")')">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>Save
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            }
```

and here is my ajax function

```
function getPage1(page)
        {
            alert("get page1");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: page,
                data: $("#frmEstDays").serialize(),
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                success: function (html) {
                    alert(html.responseText);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    var error = "Error ";
                }
            });
        }
```

here is my controller functions

```
 public ActionResult SaveSLA(SLAViewModel slavModel)
            {
                string[] ErrorMessageArray = new string[4];
                int errorIndex = 0;
                 return anything;
            }
```

Comment: It needs to be `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[i].estddays, new { .. })` (and you don't need `type = "text"` - the helper already adds that)

Comment: thanks bro problem solve

Answer (score 1):

Simply use model=>model.Items[i].PROPERTYNAME as below

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Items[i].estddays, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", MaxLength = "10" })
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `type = "text"` from `TextBoxFor` html helper.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Items.ElementAt(i).estddays, new { @class = "form-control", MaxLength = "10" })
```

The `HtmlTextboxFor` always creates a textbox `<input type="text" />`. So you don't have to specify explicitly.